# Is the tag "writing" necessary?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

It seems that most of the questions I find in *English Language and Usage* are questions that should be tagged with *writing* (including the question on when the actual punctuation raised). Using that tag sounds to me like using the tag *coding* on Stack Overflow.

Is it necessary because it has a particular meaning (which is different from the meaning I am giving to the tag)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has a particular meaning, if it is used to indicate general writing style, or to distinguish writing from speaking.  Or, if the question is less about language-y stuff and more about prose-y stuff.  It's still vague (and might still be useless), but it is not quite as vague as *coding* on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you mean that the tag could be used for questions about writing style? Should not be better to have a more specific tag, in that case?

Comment: I meant just anything strictly to do with writing and not spoken language — this might be writing style, or it might be orthography, spelling, handwriting, etc.  But I agree, there might be better, more specific tags anyway.

Comment: I think what's equivalent to *coding* on SO is our top tag: "usage". On a site *titled* "English Language and Usage", it makes just as much sense as the tags "language" or "English". It could be applied to pretty much anything: spelling, punctuation, pronunciation, idioms, dialects, even etymology, you name it. In fact, it *is* being applied to pretty much everything, hence its top position.

Comment: Very good point.  The only questions where I would object to the "usage" tag are peevy prescriptive grammar discussions that have no basis in actual usage :)